# Reverse direction of parametric equation

Tags: parametric

For the graph $y = \sqrt{x}$ the normal parametric equations would $x = t^2$ and $y = |t|$. However, the direction for that graph would be going from infinity to zero when $t \leq 0$ and zero to infinity when $t \geq 0$. I want that graph to go from zero to infinity when $t\leq 0$ and infinity to zero when $t \geq 0$. How do I reverse the direction of the parametric equations $x = t^2$ and $y = |t|$?

Comment: "However, the direction for that graph would be going from infinity to zero when $t\le0$". How do you figure that? $\lim_{t\to0}y=0$, and $\lim_{t\to-\infty^+}y=\infty$.

Comment: If t = -10, then x = 100 and y = 10, but when t = 0, x = 0 and y = 0.

Comment: So in other words, you want $y=\infty$ when $t=0$?

Comment: I don't think you expressed your idea the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Reciprocals might meet your needs, so try $x = t^{-2}$ and $y = \left|t^{-1}\right|$  and consider what this might mean (if anything) for $t=0$.